# Affect is 1, select returns updated value, however db did not change postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, typeorm

This is a very perplexing issue for me and I really hope someone an help me.

I have this update script:

```
updateBid = await this.DB.query(
UPDATE bids b SET state='${TBidState.Recalled}', updated=extract(epoch FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) * 1000000
FROM inquiries i
WHERE b.id=$1 AND b.inquiry_id=i.id
AND b.state IN  ('${TBidState.Requested}','${TBidState.Responded}','${TBidState.Offered}','${TBidState.Expired}')
AND i.parent_id=$2
RETURNING b.inquiry_id, b.teacher_id, i.parent_id`,
[bidId, Number(userId)];
```

after running this script it returns:

```
[ [ { inquiry_id: 6, teacher_id: 3, parent_id: 1 } ], 1 ]
```

I did a simple get with the bidId directly after and the retrieved information is correct. However the data did not change in the db.

Its not behaving this way for any other script I have so Im so confused. I tried running the script directly on the db and That worked fine. I also checked my orm logs and there are no errors. I dont know what else to do

Comment: Either: 1) You are updating on a different database. 2) More likely, you did not commit the transaction and the changes did not persist.

Comment: Its only one db connected to my typeorm, How do I commit the transaction on this query?. Im just calling typeorm's datasource to run this query.  Also my other update queries work

Comment: 1) I don't use TypeORM, but I did find this [Transactions](https://typeorm.io/transactions#). 2) Assuming you have `log_statements=mod` in the Postgres  `postgresql.conf` file you could check the Postgres log to see what is hitting the database.

Comment: In your typeorm config, enable logs by doing `{logging: true}`, and check what is logged when you run this update query (and after the query has been run). You can paste the entire output here.